# 2018/2019 proposed expansion of technician privileges

Tags: united-states, license, fcc

I read that arrl is petitioning the FCC to expand the privileges of the technician license. Can you summarize those changes with the schedule?

Answer (score 1):

A standard internet search produces this item from the [ARRL](http://www.arrl.org/news/arrl-requests-expanded-hf-privileges-for-technician-licensees) with the information you seek. The FCC has not yet sought public comment, which would be the first step toward a Notice of Proposed Rule Making (NPRM). Given the lack of FCC action to date, any forecast for implementation would be speculative.